# Rejecting a solution.

Tags: logarithms

Why does it for $x^2=9$ we get two solutions, while if we use the "log both sides" property the negative solution is rejected? which method is true and why?

Comment: When you write $\log(x^2)=2\log x$ you are assuming $x>0$.

Answer (score 4):

The property $\log(a^n)=n \log(a)$ is true if $a>0$ and $n \in \mathbb N$, but not if $a<0$, since $\log$ is only defined on positive real numbers.

Therefore, using $\log$ is not the right method. You should better use $x^2-9=(x-3)(x+3)$ which holds for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Many thanks dear brother

Comment: Are we in it only for the accepts?

Comment: The logarithm method works fine with this equation. You just have to be careful. The correct application would say that "$x^2=9$" is equivalent to "$2\log x = \log 9$ if $x>0$, or $2\log(-x)=\log 9$ if $x<0$". It's because $x^2$ and $(-x)^2$ are the same number.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\log_3 x^2=2\log_3|x|$, so from $x^2=9$ you get
$$
2\log_3|x|=\log_39=2
$$
and so
$$
\log_3|x|=1
$$
from which $|x|=3$.

Be careful: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.